# How color excel column based on duplicate cloumn values

Tags: vba, excel, colors, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel column called order#, that has order numbers with repeated values, as each order has one or more item, so if the order has 3 item, the order# would be repeated three times and so on.

I want to use two colors to separate between different orders, so if the first order# is "1" it would be red, and second "2" would be yellow, and third "3" would be red again, and fourth "4" would be yellow, and so on.

```
+----------+--------+
|  order#  |  item# |
+----------+--------+
|    1     |   11   |
|    2     |   12   |
|    2     |   22   |
+----------+--------+
```

Comment: if there only numbers, would be conditional formating enough? say even numbers red and odd ones yellow?

Comment: it's not must that odd and even, maybe whole sheet is even or whole sheet is odd but with different duplicate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stay with conditional formating like:

```
=MOD(ROUND(SUM(1/COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A$2:$A2)),0),2)=0
'and the other color
=MOD(ROUND(SUM(1/COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A$2:$A2)),0),2)=1
```

no need for vba or running a macro every time you change something to your list copy that formula for range like A2:B100

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick :

```
Sub test_CairoCoder()
Dim wS As Worksheet, _
    LastRow As Long, _
    ColorChg As Boolean, _
    OrderNb As String

Set wS = ActiveSheet
ColorChg = False

With wS
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    OrderNb = wS.Cells(2, 1)
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If .Cells(i, 1) <> .Cells(i + 1, 1) And .Cells(i, 1) <> .Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
            ColorChg = Not ColorChg
            If ColorChg Then
                .Range(.Cells(i, "A"), .Cells(i + 1, "A")).Interior.Color = vbRed
            Else
                .Range(.Cells(i, "A"), .Cells(i + 1, "A")).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
        Else
            If .Cells(i, 1) <> .Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
            Else
                If OrderNb <> .Cells(i, 1) Then
                    OrderNb = .Cells(i, 1)
                    ColorChg = Not ColorChg
                Else
                End If

                If ColorChg Then
                    .Range(.Cells(i, "A"), .Cells(i + 1, "A")).Interior.Color = vbRed
                Else
                    .Range(.Cells(i, "A"), .Cells(i + 1, "A")).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
MsgBox "All done!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: It's working with only repeated values, but not working with single ones.

Comment: also all sheet is colored, I want only selected column

Comment: Litteraly the selected column or the column A or the columns A and B? The edit does A and B! ;)

Comment: Perfect, but still only works with repeated values, single values has no color!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i&, x&, cl As Range, Dic As Object
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"): Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    i = [A:A].Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    x = [1:1].Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    For Each cl In Range("A2:A" & i)
        If Not Dic.exists(cl.Value2) Then
            Dic.Add cl.Value2, IIf(Dic.Count Mod 2 = 0, vbRed, vbYellow)
        End If
    Next cl
    For Each cl In Range("A2:A" & i)
        Range(cl, Cells(cl.Row, x)).Interior.Color = Dic(cl.Value2)
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the column you want to change color. Chose formatting and format column. You can edit or customize all properties at one place. [Excel templates](http://www.xltemplates.org) offer huge number of templates designed using Microsoft Excel. Hope vising this will help you understand excel in relation to pre-design templates.